# Receiving multidimensional array from C api, how to handle in Swift?

Tags: ios, c, arrays, swift

I use a C library in my Swift application and I cannot figure out how to get the multidimensional array that the C method is supposed to return.

I receive this from the C API:

```
struct resultArray
{
    double *data;
    int size[2];
};
```

Where:

size = the matrix size, a two element array with the number of rows and number of columns

data = the matrix data

In swift I can do the following to get the size:

```
let numRows = Int(results.size.0)
let numColoumns = Int(results.size.1)
```

But I don't understand how to get the matrix so that I can iterate through it? I tried the following:

```
let matrixResult = results.data.memory
```

This seems to return only a double value because matrixResult becomes a Double.

Then I tried this:

```
let matrixResult = results.data
```

Which makes the matrixResult an:

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>
```

I expect to receive a matrix as specified in the C library documentation. Then I want to iterate through this matrix and get the values from the first row and put it in a Swift array... Does somebody know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *matrix* type in C. Assuming that `data` is a pointer to 
the contiguous matrix elements stored as an *array*, you would copy the
first row to a Swift array with

```
let firstRow = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: results.data, count: numColumns))
```

and the entire "matrix" to a nested Swift array with

```
let matrix = (0 ..< numRows).map { row in
    Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: results.data + numColumns * row, count: numColumns))
}
```

Alternatively (and this is similar to what [Melifaro suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37134249/1187415)), you can create an array
of pointers pointing into the matrix rows:

```
let matrix = (0 ..< numRows).map { row in
    UnsafeBufferPointer(start: results.data + numColumns * row, count: numColumns)
}
```

This still allows to address arbitrary elements in a matrix-like fashion

```
 let element = matrix[row][col]
```

but does not copy the data. Of course this requires that the matrix data
is valid throughout the use of `matrix`, as the memory is not managed
by Swift.

Comment: This works! Thank you, finally I understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, If you work with huge data set, it makes sense to deal with data in the C-Structure directly, instead of duplicating it in Swift data structure. So one another way to do the same:

```
let (I, J) = res.size

for i in 0..<I {
    for j in 0..<J {
        let v = res.data.advancedBy(Int(j + i * J))
        let d: Double = v.memory
        print("[\(i), \(j)]: \(d)")
    }
}
```